# Uploaded documents of extensions .docx /.xlsx with metaData, metaData are not saved

Tags: office-365, metadata

When the documents with extensions .docx /.xlsx is/are uploaded along with metadata mandatory fields on SharePoint online. These mandatory fields are empty. Any reason?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved, I have implemented Deferred and Promise in our jquery code. Initially document is uploaded in the document list and then second function is called to update metaData values..